# Encode data to send to javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

Hi I'm trying to send data to a javascript function from my grails controller. I already use escape() but it doesn't help. The following is what Fiddler shows. I suppose is the line break that cause the issue..

controller:

```
render(text:content, contentType: "text/javascript")
```

data:

```
addPestMarker( 6, escape('White Fly'), escape('Bemisia tabaci                                 ') ,  escape( 'N/A'), escape(' N/A'), escape('N/A'), escape('Install sticky fly traps.'), escape('Nymph measures to 0.3-0.8mm long. Size is about 1mm long with wings. They possess arrhenotoky where unfertilized eggs produce male flies while fertilized eggs produce female flies. Each female can produce 200 eggs in her life time. For whiteflies, development period takes 30 to 40 days depending on temperature.'), '35.0', '70.0','null', 'null');
```

Comment: json..? if you're using php, try json_encode

Comment: It could be the hyphens e.g., 10 - 15. Try without them.

Comment: what error do you have on client-side?

Comment: what you mean with 'data'. what is it? text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is `return content as JSON`. Grails will serialize `content` to JSON and use a proper contet type.